# Как правильно подключить CKEditor5 в Laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

в app.js подключаю так

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
        minHeight: '300px',
        plugins: [Bold],
        toolbar: ['bold']
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    });
```

после сборки выдает

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at IconView._updateXMLContent (admin.js:45967)
    at IconView.render (admin.js:45943)
    at IconView.<anonymous> (admin.js:57293)
    at IconView.fire (admin.js:55108)
    at IconView.<computed> [as render] (admin.js:57297)
    at ViewCollection._renderViewIntoCollectionParent (admin.js:50439)
    at ViewCollection.<anonymous> (admin.js:50300)
    at ViewCollection.fire (admin.js:55108)
    at ViewCollection.add (admin.js:51258)
    at ButtonView.render (admin.js:43580)
```

Comment: где app.js подключается?

Comment: в blade app.blade или вы про что?

Comment: в html где подключается?

Comment: в главном файле шаблона app.blade.php внизу страницы